# How to delete rows from DataTable with LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have the following code to delete rows from DataTable:

```
var rows = dTable.Select("col1 ='ali'");
foreach (var row in rows)
   row.Delete();
```

above code work fine. how to **convert** this code to **LINQ**?

Comment: FYI linq uses loop internally too!

Comment: Why'd you like to do it in linq?

Comment: @KingKing Why? `rows` is `DataRow[]` what stops you to delete?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I was so not careful when reading, in fact `row.Delete()` will modify the collection `dTable.Rows` not `rows`.

Comment: @KingKing It happens..

Answer (score 44, accepted):

LINQ is not for deleting or modifying - it is for **querying** data. With LINQ you can select data which should be deleted, and then delete those data manually (e.g. in foreach loop or with ForEach list extension):

```
var query = dTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("col1") == "ali");

foreach(var row in query.ToList())
   row.Delete();
```

UPDATE: Also with LINQ to DataSet you can select all rows which should stay in table and create new DataTable from those rows:

```
var table = dTable.AsEnumerable()
                  .Where(r => r.Field<string>("col1") != "ali")
                  .CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Error: Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.

Comment: @SamieyMehdi sorry, fixed. Also added alternative solution to show how LINQ works - you either select what to delete, or select what should stay.

Comment: @SamieyMehdi I'm completely sure it works. Please check your code - possibly you are missing `ToList()` call

Comment: @SamieyMehdi `Collection was modified` error was there because datatable enumerator throws exception if table was modified while you are using enumerator (so do lists, when you are trying to modify them if foreach).

Comment: @SamieyMehdi how doesn't it work? `row.Delete()` **won't** modify `query.ToList()`, so it should work.

Answer (score 11):

Try this inline lambda code with extension methodes:

```
  dTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field("col1") == "ali").ToList().ForEach(row => row.Delete());
  dTable.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: Mohamed Salemyan I think  r.Field("col1") would be r.Field<string>("col1") this give error.

Comment: Yes Adil. I wrote the code with <string> but some one edit my code and remove <string> type. I rolled back the edit but yet change not committed.

Answer (score 3):

you use for loop or while loop to delete rows but not foreach

below is non linq solution

```
dTable= dTable.Select("col1 <> 'ali'").CopyToDataTable();
```

LINQ

```
dTable = dTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("col1") != "ali").CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: That deletes everything *else*.  Even if you invert the condition, you're now copying a whole bunch more data, assuming the rows to keep are much more than the rows to delete.

Comment: @SamieyMehdi you even doesn't notice the `Servy's comment`? If your DataTable is large and you just need to delete some rows, doing like this will be very inefficient.

Comment: Not to mention the fact that the question specifically asks for a LINQ solution, and this has none (but that's less of a problem than the previously mentioned inefficient approach).

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = from row in dTable.Tables["tablename"].AsEnumerable()
          where row.Field<string>("Col1") == "ali" 
          select row;
foreach (DataRow row in results)
{
   dTable.Tables["tablename"].Remove(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DataRow[] rows;
rows=dataTable.Select("UserName = 'ABC'"); // UserName is Column Name
foreach(DataRow r in rows)
r.Delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched far and wide (well, more than four Google searches) for a solution to this and in the end I eventually gleaned (above in Sergey Berezovskiy's post) that LINQ doesn't do deletes - so you use LINQ to select the rows you want to get rid of and delete them through the 'usual' mechanism of the database technology in use. Seems to make all that database-agnostic propaganda about LINQ pretty silly?

This does work although with a little more experimentation one might be able to reduce the two 'For Each' loops to one.

I had a table of Properties where I wanted to delete all the entries with a chosen property name (3rd keyfield) for a particular ObjectType (1st Keyfield) and I came up with this.

FYI the REPLY object is a bit like the Error object - I just package error messages, a binary Pass/fail flag and a few other things so I can pass back loads of stuff from a query and (eventually) show the error to the user.

```
  ' <summary>
  ' The user has decided they don't want a particular property type so we delete all
  ' properties of that type in the table - belonging to any object of that ObjectType
  ' </summary>
  ' <param name="sObjectType"></param>
  ' <param name="sName"></param>
  ' <returns></returns>
  ' <remarks></remarks>
  Public Function DeleteAllPropsByName(sObjectType As String, sName As String) As Reply

    ' Default answer is 'OK'
    DeleteAllPropsByName = New Reply(True)

    Dim T As DataTable = mDB.DataTableImage(msTableName)
    Dim q = From rw In T.AsEnumerable
            Where rw.Field(Of String)("ObjectType") = sObjectType _
            And rw.Field(Of String)("PropName") = sName

    ' Somewhere to remember our list of target rows to delete
    Dim rows As New List(Of DataRow)

    For Each row In q
      '
      ' LINQ doesn't delete so we need to delete from the Datatable directly.
      ' If we delete here we get the collection modified error so we have to save 
      ' the datarows to ANOTHER list and then delete them from there.
      rows.Add(row)

    Next

    For Each rw As DataRow In rows
      '
      ' Call the Delete routine in my table class passing it the 
      ' primary key of the row to delete
      '
      DeleteAllPropsByName = gDB.Table(msTableName).Delete( _
                                  rw.Item("ObjectType").ToString, _
                                  CInt(rw.Item("ObjectID")), _
                                  rw.Item("PropName").ToString)

      If Not DeleteAllPropsByName.OK Then
        ' The reply object (in DeleteAllPropsByName) has all the error info so we can just
        ' exit and return it if the delete failed.
        Exit Function
      End If

    Next

  End Function
```

Answer (score -1):

```
dTable.Rows.Remove(dTable.AsEnumerable().Where(r => r.Field<string>("col1") == "Ali").FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: This would be better with an explanation, as well as code that matches the OP's fields/values.

Comment: This is will delete only one row from the datatable