# Remove Column from Dataset having same row values

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, datatable, dataset

```
ID   Name      Value
 ......................
 1     aa      123
 2     bb      123
 3     cd      123
```

Wanted to remove column "value" which has all the row values equal to 123 from Dataset using linq

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854395/how-to-delete-rows-from-datatable-with-linq

Comment: Do you want to remove the column from the table if all values are the same?

Comment: wanted to find and delete the column were all the values are same in that column.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delet the whole column if all values are the same use `Enumerable.All`, for example in:

```
foreach(DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
{
   if(dt.Rows.Count > 0 && dt.Columns.Contains("Value") && dt.Columns["Value"].DataType == typeof(int))
   {
       int firstValue = dt.Rows[0].Field<int>("Value");
       if(dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(1).All(r => r.Field<int>("Value") == firstValue))
       {
           dt.Columns.Remove("Value");
       }
   }
}
```

**Update**: *"wanted to find and delete the column were all the values are same in that column.*"

Then you just have to  generalize above code:

```
foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
{
    List<DataColumn> columnsToDelete = new List<DataColumn>();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        object first = dt.Rows[0][col];
        if (dt.AsEnumerable().Skip(1).All(r => r[col].Equals(first)))
        {
            columnsToDelete.Add(col);
        }
    }
    foreach (DataColumn colToRemove in columnsToDelete)
        dt.Columns.Remove(colToRemove);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here return in list of datarow

```
ds.Tables["tableName"].AsEnumerable().Where(g => g.Field<Int32>("Value") != 123).ToList<DataRow>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Worked with the solution given by SLaks https://stackoverflow.com/a/1766950/848286

```
foreach (var column in ds.Tables[0].Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().ToArray())
        {
            if (ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable().All(dr => dr.IsNull(column)))
            {
                ds.Tables[0].Columns.Remove(column);
            }
        }
```

Comment: But it seems not to do what you want, does it? _"wanted to find and delete the column were all the values are same in that column."_ This just checks if the dataset's first table's first column  contains only `123`. So if it all are `111` the column is not removed. You have't mentioned either that you only what to check a single column of one table. Please  specify your requirement  more precisely next time.

Comment: This iterates through the columns and check if all the row values are same. then deletes that column

Comment: But it does not even compile since `dr[column]` returns `object` whereas `123` is an `int`. You cannot compare both with `==`.