# How do I remove elements from an object of type Table?

Tags: c#, linq

My code is

```
if (selectedOrgName != "All")
{
    // Get the orgid corresponding to the selected organization
    var selectedOrgId = PD.orgs.FirstOrDefault(o => o.orgname == selectedOrgName); 

    // Return error message if no such oranization name exists
    if (selectedOrgId == null) 
    {
        return Content("Couldn't find row for organization '" + selectedOrgName + 
        "' in the database."); 
    }

    foreach (var f in PD.files) if (f.orgid != selectedOrgId.orgid) f.Delete();

} // if search is filtered by a specific organization
```

except `Delete()` isn't recognized by the compiler. Strange because [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18854395/how-to-delete-rows-from-datatable-with-linq) posted equivalent code and said it worked. What function do I really want?

The `PD.files` is a `Table<AssetFile>` where `AssetFile` is defined as

```
[Table( Name = "files" )] 
public class AssetFile 
{ 
    public AssetFile() { } 

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]         
    public int fileid { get; set; } 

    [Column] 
    public int orgid { get; set; } 

    [Column] 
    public int catid { get; set; } 

    [Column]
    public string filename { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: What is type of PD.files?

Comment: `Table<AssetFile>` where `AssetFile` is defined by `    [Table( Name = "files" )]
    public class AssetFile
    {
        public AssetFile()
        {

        }

        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true)]
        public int fileid { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public int orgid { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public int catid { get; set; }
        [Column]
        public string filename { get; set; }
    }
`

Comment: The linked question is about DataTable not Table<TEntity>.

Comment: How do I do the equivalent on `Table<TEntity>`

Comment: Maybe [Table<TEntity>RemoveOnSubmit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763473(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: @CantGetLaid Given the code you have is incorrect let's see if we can get you some correct code.  **First** off could you edit the original question with the definition of AssetFile?  **Second** What are you trying to do with the delete.  Are you trying to prune the local Entity table or do you want to delete it from the DB also?

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You must use `DeleteOnSubmit` method.
In your case

```
foreach (var f in PD.files)
{
    if (f.orgid != selectedOrgId.orgid)
    {
        PD.files.DeleteOnSubmit(f);
    }
}
PD.SubmitChanges();
```

See [this link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763473(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details.

Comment: I don't want to actually delete it from the database

Comment: In that case you should say what exactly you do want to do. If you want to create a view different from the database model, you should maybe use an `ObservableCollection` or `IEnumerable` for example. Those should be easy enough to filter to suit your view needs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `AssetFile` isn't a `DataRow` in a `DataTable`. It's just an object in a collection (a LINQ-to-SQL `Table<T>`) and it doesn't have a `Delete` method as `DataRow` has.

What you probably want is this:

```
 var files =  PD.files
                .Where(f => f.orgid == selectedOrgId.orgid)
                .ToList();
```

...so you end up with a list from which the files having a different `orgid` are "deleted" (in reality: not added).